# undefined fetchAll and fetch in an returned PDOStatement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, undefined

I'm just beginning with PDO and have look up in several tutorials for an answer but I just can't make it work.

I got

```
Notice: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$fetch in E:\-------- on line 22 
Result: 1
```

with

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=the_database;";
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, "root", "");
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
} catch (PDOException $e){
    die( "failed conexion: ".$e->getMessage() );
}


$query = "SELECT MAX(price) AS max, MIN(price) AS min FROM cellphones";
try {
    $sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
    $sth->execute();
    $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $result = $sth->fetchAll;
    }
catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
die( "<br />Result: ".print_r($result, true) );
```

I get the same result with

```
$sth = $dbh->query($query);
$result = $sth->fetchAll;
```

and

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch;
```

What I do get is that it might be returning the count of results
But why? And why it gives me a Notice about fetch / fetchAll not even declared.
I don't get any exception either.

Comment: Also, unrelated, that is a misuse of `print_r`. If you're concatenating, use it like this: `print_r($result,true)`

Comment: thanks! now is corrected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the method call with paranthesis:

```
$sth->fetchAll();
```

Or 
    $sth->fetch();

not just

```
$sth->fetchAll;
```

PHP thinks your trying to hit a property called fetchAll!

Comment: @Sdlion np... It's always the obvious ones that are hard to find!